# Ça veut dire quoi l'expression "porter sur des moyens" ?

Tags: expressions

J'écoutais une [vidéo sur YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PJ2xR9-o94&t=250s) où j'ai entendu l'expression "porter sur des moyens pour…"

Pour le contexte, voici toute la phrase:

> Ces violences sont illégitimes par essence et ne sont pas la conséquence d'une revendication politique ou sociale qui porterait sur des moyens pour les banlieues.

Bien que je l'ai cherchée en ligne, je ne trouve rien sur cette expression. Quelqu'un peut-il me l'expliquer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cela signifie que la *revendication* serait à propos de *moyens pour les banlieues*. Les *moyens* en question sont un peu vagues. On peut imaginer des fonds (de l'argent) pour améliorer l'environnement et les services dans ces banlieues.

Des *moyens* ici sont des *moyens* pour accomplir quelque chose, et pourraient être des investissements, mais aussi du personnel, ou toute autre *ressource* nécessaire dans l'accomplissement d'un but.

Quant à l'expression "porter sur", elle signifie bien ici "être à propos de/au sujet de". On trouve également parfois *se rapporter à* avec le même sens.

Comment: @jiliagre - Merci pour les corrections! :-)

Answer (score -1):

C'est une construction typique du jargon politique: personne ne parle comme cela en-dehors de discours politiques (mal écrits). Cependant, in n'y a pas d'erreur d'un point de vue grammatical.

> Ces violences sont illégitimes par essence et ne sont pas la conséquence d'une revendication politique ou sociale qui porterait sur des moyens pour les banlieues.

Si j'ajoute des parenthèses pour mettre en relief la manière dont s'imbriquent les différentes propostions:

> Ces violences sont {illégitimes par essence} et [ces violences] ne sont pas {la conséquence de {une revendication politique ou sociale qui porterait sur {des moyens pour les banlieues}}}.

> "des moyens pour les banlieues" ("means for suburbs")

La plupart des gens comprendraient ceci comme "des moyens pour donner une meilleure vie aux habitants des banlieues" (comme de l'argent pour des infrastructures, des fonctionnaires, des évènements culturels, le financement d'associations locales...), mais c'est aussi un 'dog-whistle'* qui signifie "des moyens pour faire en sorte que les banlieues ne soient pas un problème pour ceux qui n'y vivent pas" (comme des descentes de police plus sévères, des écoles séparées, ou même des murs pour empêcher leurs habitants de circuler ailleurs).

Si on développe la phrase, selon le sens qu'on retient, on arrive à deux significations différentes:

- "Les violences que vous voyez ne sont pas issues de revendications légitimes, comme demander à ce que les banlieues soient plus vivables. (Sous-entendu: "vous qui habitez ces banlieues, ces gens sont vos ennemis.")
- "Nous ne retenons aucun lien entre toutes les mesures qui ont été prises à l'encontre des habitants des banlieues pour le bénéfice de gens plus riches et le fait que ces gens soient fâchés au point de l'émeute." (Sous-entendu: "vous qui n'habitez pas les banlieues, ne vous inquiétez pas on est de votre côté.")

Je ne sais pas d'où vient cette phrase mais ça ne m'étonnerait pas si la source était un média particulièrement réactionnaire.

---

*Je n'ai pas de bonne traduction pour 'dog-whistle' dans ce sens précis où il s'agit d'une expression destinée à faire passer un signal à une communauté précise tout en n'étant pas remarqué du grand public.

Comment: Il s'agit du compte rendu du Conseil des ministres du 5 juillet 2023 par Olivier Véran.

Comment: +1  pour le double sens possible. Ton commentaire sur le _dog whistle_ est très intéressant, mais les moyens sont la cible de la revendication ici - sait-on d'après le contexte _qui_ ferait la revendication? Est-ce les gens des banlieues? Ou quelqu'un d'autre? Je ne sais pas si ceux qui n'habitent pas dans les banlieues ont fait, explicitement ou implicitement, une revendication de "pacification" des banlieues. A voir.

Comment: @Frank: avec le contexte fourni par jiliagre, le *dog-whistle* est possiblement addressé à l'électorat d'(extrême-)droite, dans la même mouvance que le fameux projet de "nettoyer les banlieues au karcher" de Nicolas Sarkozy quelques années plus tôt.  Ou alors possiblement aux sponsors du gouvernement (des milliardaires dont des boutiques de luxe ont été pillées pendant les émeutes).

Comment: @AnneAunyme Je vois bien, mais un peu bizarre d'utiliser le mot _revendication_ dans ce cas-là. Une _revendication_ c'est plutôt "agressif" au début d'un conflit social, mais je ne sais pas si des moyens pour nettoyer les banlieues "au karcher" auraient été "revendiquées".

Comment: @Frank: une revendication c'est simplement, (d'après Larousse par exemple): l'action de réclamer ce qui est dû. Cela peut tout autant être des citoyens qui demandent que leur avis pèse dans les décisions politiques (parce qu'on estime que c'est dû en démocratie), ou des milliardiares qui demandent qu'on protège leurs boutiques de luxe (parce qu'ils estiment que ce serait un retour d'ascenseur normal après avoir financé la campagne politique du dirigeant).

Comment: @AnneAunyme Dans le cas précis de cette phrase et des émeutes qui l'ont motivée, ton analyse est exagérée. Les LIDL, Franprix et autres commerces en priorité visés par les émeutiers peuvent difficilement être qualifiés de boutiques de luxe, de même que les voitures détruites ou les équipement collectifs attaqués (bus, RER, les écoles ou des maisons des jeunes). Des sondages indiquent que ces émeutes ont été condamnées par 85 % de la population, ce qui déborde (j'espère) largement de l'extrême droite. Ce n'est essentiellement que l'extrême gauche populiste qui a évité de condamner les émeutes.

Comment: @jlliagre: Les éléments protégés par la police lors des émeutes n'étaient pas les LIDL, Franprix, ni les véhicules particuliers, c'était bien les boutiques de luxe. Il est raisonnable de penser que ces boutiques ont été protégées en priorité car leurs propriétaires en on fait la demande, directement ou indirectement. Je n'ai pas trouvé de sondage sur le sujet du point de vue des français, pourriez-vous communiquer vos sources? Enfin, je crois qu'on n'a pas la même définition de l'extrême-gauche.

Comment: Et de toutes façons même en supposant que la quasi-totalité des français soient révoltés par la violence des émeutes, ça ne veut pas dire qu'ils et elles ne blâment pas le gouvernement pour celles-ci. Le déclencheur de ces émeutes ça n'est pas l'opposition politique qui refuse de répéter ce qu'on lui dit de dire au mot près: c'est un meurtre causé par un policier dans un contexte de tensions suite à des actions du gouvernement de plus en plus brutales. Que le gouvernement refuse d'admettre toute responsabilité ça n'est pas politiquement correct, ça a du sens de passer par un dog-whistle.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Ok, "extrême gauche" n'est effectivement pas le terme qui convient pour LFI. 85 % était peut-être sous estimé, [ici](https://elabe.fr/police-emeutes-urbaines/) : *93%* [des sondés] *condamnent les violences contre les bâtiments publics et 89% les violences contre la police.* et *Seuls 10% estiment que les émeutiers ont une réaction de colère et un sentiment d’injustice face à la mort de Nahel.* Pour le reste, il semble qu'on ne pourra pas tomber d'accord mais ce n'est pas grave. Après tout, FSE (n')est (qu')un site sur la langue française...